# Why does this error come up when I add cloud code?

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I just migrated from parse to heroku and everything works, but when I add cloud code I get this error in my iOS app `Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})`. This only happens when I add cloud code and nothing loads, but after taking it out it works perfectly fine.

```
var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://xxxxxxx',
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'xxxxxxxxx',
masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'xxxxxxxx', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
liveQuery: {
classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});


let config = ParseClientConfiguration(block: {
        (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "xxxxxxxxx";
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "http://yyyyyyy.herokuapp.com/parse";
    });
Parse.initialize(with: config);
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post some code.. it's very hard to understand the issue without any code snippets..

Comment: I don't think it's my code it works on parse. Plus my code is over 1000 lines

Comment: I don't need all the code. Are you getting this error when you are trying to configure cloud code for your parse-server project?

Comment: When I copy and paste my cloud code from parse to the main.js in my heroku project I get this error

Comment: That's because cloud code in parse-server and in parse.com are not 100% compatible. Can you please add your cloud code. or only the code that is not working for you..

Comment: I don't know specifically which part of the code works and its way to big to share. I do know that I don't call any cloud functions till you go deep into the app, so I'm not calling any functions when they first start up the app. When I first start the app with the cloud code in main.js nothing loads when I take it out everything loads

Comment: ok so please put the code where you initiate the parse server. i want to see if you configure the cloud code correctly ..

Comment: Initiate it in my iOS app?

Comment: no.. in your server side.. the NodeJS side

Comment: @RanHassid I updated my question with the code

Comment: can you post your iOS code where you initialize the parse iOS SDK? your parse server initialize looks good

Comment: @RanHassid I updated my code

Comment: looks ok.. In your cloud code are you require some other files? if the answer is yes.. can you show how you require them?

Comment: I don't need to require any other files